# Textarea in read only state text display is not full

Tags: html, css

problem
[image: problem]
normal
[image: normal]

html

```
<textarea id="dataForm:DESCRIBE" name="dataForm:DESCRIBE"  
style="width:100% !important;height:120px !important; overflow: visible !important;"></textarea>
```

css:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
```

js code (textarea is readonly):

```
if (value==true&&(otype=="text"||otype=="textarea"||otype=="select-one")){
  $(name).readOnly = true;
  $(name).onclick  = "";
  $(name).style.background="#F4F4F4";
  if (otype=="select-one"){
    $(name).disabled = value;
  }
}
else{
  $(name).disabled = value;
}
```

We try to mark height !important,but it does't work. If delete css style

```
{ 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 48px;   
 border: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
```

It works but style  is Browser  default.

my local service  web page have no problem, but the production environment of the web service is not normal .for some reason,I can't debug the production environment by myself.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Have you tried setting the rows and cols properties on textarea?

Comment: thank you very much , I set the rows ,it becomes to normal .however  I  still don't understand why rows can cause this problem. and readyonly=false  without this  .

Answer (score 0):

Without context, I am not entirely sure what you are doing, or what the problem is. I created a working example below where jQuery can toggle readonly for a textarea or an input. Hope that helps.

```js
$("#toggle-readonly").click(function(){
  $textarea = $("textarea[name=dataForm\\:DESCRIBE]");
  
  if($textarea.attr("readonly") !== undefined){ 
    //This is the line thar really counts
    $("textarea[name=dataForm\\:DESCRIBE]").removeAttr('readonly')
  } else{
    $("textarea[name=dataForm\\:DESCRIBE]").attr('readonly','readonly');
  }
  
 
});
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="dataForm:DESCRIBE" name="dataForm:DESCRIBE">This is placeholder text...</textarea>

<button id="toggle-readonly">Toggle Readonly</button>
```

Comment: thank for you help,but the problem is not about add readonly .